# Optimizing self join on all columns in an ms access table - without any conditions/clauses

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, self-join

I am coding in ms access using vba.

I am trying to self join a table in ms access . 
It has 8 columns and I need a Cartesian product for all.

The problem is the query I have written takes too long to execute (more than 30 mins!) . Need help on how to optimise it.

The query written is as follows:

```
  INSERT INTO table1 
  SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3, t4.col4, t5.col5,
    t6.col6,t7.col7,t8.col8 
  from
    table1 as t1, table1 as t2, table1 as t3, table1 as t4, table1 as t5,  
    table1 as t6, table1 as t7, table1 as t8;
```

I checked other threads but found none which could answer my query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just need the Cartesian product of what is currently in the table or for every row in the table? If you could explain a little more it would be helpful. It is just a little confusing I don't think that your current query is doing what you want.  Maybe explain in more detail your exact expected results.

Comment: **How many rows of data are in the table?** The cartesian product of 8 tables can turn into a lot of data veeery quickly: supposing you only had 100 records in the table, you would get 100^8 = 10^16 = ten quadrillion records... which is just rediculous.

Comment: Yes, why on earth would you want to do this? What is your primary intention, i.e. what do you want to gain from the result?